# Exercise 3(b) on p.132 in "Analysis on Manifolds" by James R. Munkres. I cannot solve this exercise.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, improper-integrals

I am reading "Analysis on Manifolds" by James R. Munkres.

The following exercise is Exercise 3(b) on p.132.

> Exercise 3(b) Let $C=\{(x,y)\mid x>0\text{ and }y>0\}.$ Let $$f(x,y)=1/(x^2+\sqrt{x})(y^2+\sqrt{y}).$$ Show that $\int_C f$ exists; do not attempt to calculate it.

I tried to solve this exercise.
But I cannot solve this exercise.

> **Theorem 15.6.** Let $A$ be open in $\mathbb{R}^n$; let $f:A\to\mathbb{R}$ be continuous. Let $U_1\subset U_2\subset\cdots$ be a sequence of open sets whose union is $A$. Then $\int_A f$ exists if and only if the sequence $\int_{U_N} |f|$ exists and is bounded; in this case, $$\int_A f=\lim_{N\to\infty}\int_{U_N} f.$$

> **Theorem 15.3(d)** (Additivity). Suppose $A$ and $B$ are open in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $f$ is continuous on $A\cup B$. If $f$ is integrable on $A$ and $B$, then $f$ is integrable on $A\cup B$ and $A\cap B$, and $$\int_{A\cup B}f=\int_A f+\int_B f-\int_{A\cap B} f.$$

My attempt is here:

> Fix $N\in\{1,2,\dots\}$.
> Let $U_M:=(\frac{1}{N},M)$ for $M=2,3,\dots$.
> Let $g(x,y):=\frac{1}{x^2y^2}$.
> The set $U_M$ is rectifiable; $f$ and $g$ are bounded on $U_M$ because $\overline{U_M}$ is compact and $f$ and $g$ are continuous on $\overline{U_M}$. Thus $\int_{U_M}f$ and $\int_{U_M}g$ exists as an ordinary integral, so we can apply "Comparison" (Theorem 13.3(b) on p.106) to $\int_{U_M}f$ and $\int_{U_M}g$ and we can apply the Fubini theorem to $\int_{U_M}g$. We compute $$\int_{U_M}f\leq\int_{U_M}g=\int_{x=\frac{1}{N}}^{x=M}\int_{y=\frac{1}{N}}^{y=M}\frac{1}{x^2y^2}=(N-\frac{1}{M})^2<N^2.$$
> So, $f$ is integrable over $(\frac{1}{N},\infty)\times (\frac{1}{N},\infty)$ by Theorem 15.6 above.
>
> ---
>
> Fix $M\in\{2,3,\dots\}$.
> Let $V_N:=(\frac{1}{N},M)$ for $N=1,2,\dots$.
> Let $h(x,y):=\frac{1}{\sqrt{xy}}$.
> The set $V_N$ is rectifiable; $f$ and $h$ are bounded on $V_N$ because $\overline{V_N}$ is compact and $f$ and $h$ are continuous on $\overline{V_N}$. Thus $\int_{V_N}f$ and $\int_{V_N}h$ exists as an ordinary integral, so we can apply "Comparison" (Theorem 13.3(b) on p.106) to $\int_{V_N}f$ and $\int_{V_N}h$ and we can apply the Fubini theorem to $\int_{V_N}h$. We compute $$\int_{V_N}f\leq\int_{V_N}h=\int_{x=\frac{1}{N}}^{x=M}\int_{y=\frac{1}{N}}^{y=M}\frac{1}{\sqrt{xy}}=4(\sqrt{M}-\sqrt{\frac{1}{N}})^2<4M.$$
> So, $f$ is integrable over $(0,M)\times (0,M)$ by Theorem 15.6 above.

Answer (score 1):

Let $U_N:=(\frac{1}{N},2)\times (1,N)$ for $N=1,2,\dots$.

We compute $$\int_{U_N}f\leq\int_{x=\frac{1}{N}}^{x=2}\int_{y=1}^{y=N}\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\frac{1}{y^2}=(2\sqrt{2}-2\sqrt{\frac{1}{N}})(1-\frac{1}{N})<2\sqrt{2}.$$
So, $f$ is integrable over $(0,2)\times (1,\infty)$ by Theorem 15.6 above.

Similarly, $f$ is integrable over $(1,\infty)\times (0,2)$ by Theorem 15.6 above.

$f$ is integrable over $(0,2)\times (0,2)$ by my attempt.
$f$ is integrable over $(1,\infty)\times (1,\infty)$ by my attempt.

And $(0,2)\times (0,2)\cup (1,\infty)\times (1,\infty)\cup (0,2)\times (1,\infty)\cup (1,\infty)\times (0,2)=C.$
By Theorem 15.3(d), $f$ is integrable over $C$.

---

By the way, $\int_C f=\frac{16}{27}\pi^2.$

I calculated the above value by Wolfram Engine:

```
reg = ImplicitRegion[0 < x && 0 < y, {x, y}];  
int = Integrate[1/((x^2 + Sqrt[x]) (y^2 + Sqrt[y])), {x, y} \[Element] reg]
```